# Separate ASCII from binary in a socket transmission

Tags: java, inputstream

I have to decode a socket transmission which contains pieces of a file:

```
data %filekey% [3:%piece3% 5:%piece5% 7:%piece7% 8:%piece8% 9:%piece9%]
```

- `%pieceN%` contains the N-th binary piece of the file
- Pieces' lengths are known
- `%filekey%` is known
- Indexes are known (but maybe not in the right order)
- Everything but the pieces is ASCII
- This message ends with a carriage return (`\n`).
- This "protocol" can't be changed.

I'm facing two problems:

- I can extract the line from my `InputStream`, looking for `\n`. But what if a byte from `%pieceN%` also contains a carriage return ?
- To split each pieces and its corresponding index, I have to find `N:`. Just like my previous question: what if `%pieceN%` contains a `:` ?

Comment: As JB Nizet said the protocol is not complete.  In order for it to be complete it would need to allow for escaping any characters that are used to separate data.

Comment: How arbitrary are these `%pieceN%`s? Do you know how long they're expected to be? Are there any limitations *at all* on what they can be?

Comment: @ruakh: I edited my question according to your needs.

Comment: How about the `]` itself? It can be the terminator of a line instead of `\n`

Comment: @eee As I said, I can't modify the protocol. End of message = `\n`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't say it can be modified... Ok, I want to know whether `]` is part of the sentence format or not. If yes, it can be used as a terminator for you to decode (to extract data up to the character `]`). Since it is not guaranteed that the data will be complete, perform a loop to read data into a buffer until `]` is found and decode the buffer.

Comment: @eee: nothing prevents pieces from containing `]` too :(

Comment: Well, even when ruakh's answer is the viable solution, the data protocol itself is flawed in design since it doesn't give a way to escape some characters/symbols that are used in the protocol.

Comment: @eee: Given that each field has a predefined length, the protocol isn't really flawed. I don't think it's a *great* design, but there are no formal ambiguities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the lengths of every part of `data %filekey% [3:%piece3% 5:%piece5% 7:%piece7% 8:%piece8% 9:%piece9%]` — you know the number of spaces, you know what `%filekey%` is, you know the lengths of each `%pieceN%`, etc. — this means you know the full length of `data %filekey% [3:%piece3% 5:%piece5% 7:%piece7% 8:%piece8% 9:%piece9%]`, so you can just use [`java.io.InputStream.read(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5b%5d)) or [`.read(byte[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int)) to read the exact number of bytes you need. (N.B. those methods both return an `int` to indicate the number of bytes they actually read. You may need to call them in a loop to ensure that you fill your byte-array.) Don't worry about searching for `\n`.

Comment: Do I assume that an ASCII character is an 8-bit length ?

Comment: @Idiqual: That's determined by the protocol, but -- yes. Almost certainly.